# JS working with two array

Tags: javascript

I need to create an array `cells` as described in my comment.
I would like to know what is wrong with this script, and the more perfomant way to achieve this result.

Look at the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XvTrf/5/

```
var data = ['D-0','D-1','D-2','D-3','D-4','D-5','D-6','D-7','D-8','D-9'];

var cells=[];
var d = 0, lenD = data.length;

while(d< lenD){
    if(d === 1 || d === 5 || d ===6){
       cells.push('test');
    }else {
        cells.push(data[d]);
    }
    d++;
}
console.log(cells);


/* result wanted
D-0
test
D-1
D-2
D-3
test
test
D-4
D-5
D-6
D-7
D-8
D-9

*/
```

Comment: the solution is not equal to what you wanted: ["D-0", "test", "D-1", "D-2", "D-3", "D-4", "test", "D-5", "test", "D-6", "D-7", "D-8", "D-9"] vs ["D-0", "TEST", "D-1", "D-2", "D-3", "TEST","TEST", "D-4", "D-5", "D-6", "D-7", "D-8", "D-9"]

Comment: thanks for commenting, I made an edit to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The else statement means that some entries are not being entered.

Additionally, you could make use of the `splice` method... this will result in less code but also less speed.

```
var data = ['D-0','D-1','D-2','D-3','D-4','D-5','D-6','D-7','D-8','D-9'];

var cells= data.slice(0);;
cells.splice(1, 0, "TEST");
cells.splice(5, 0, "TEST");
cells.splice(6, 0, "TEST");
console.log(cells);

alert(cells);
```

If you want to see the difference in speed:

http://jsfiddle.net/DBhPB/1/

### Update

A faster solution is to pre-allocate your array size, instead of using the `push` method.

```
var data = ['D-0', 'D-1', 'D-2', 'D-3', 'D-4', 'D-5', 'D-6', 'D-7', 'D-8', 'D-9'];

var cells = new Array(data.length + 3);

var d = 0,
    insertions = 0,
    lenD = cells.length;


while (d < lenD) {

    if (d === 1 || d === 5 || d === 6) {
        cells[d] = 'test';
        insertions++;
        d++;
    }
    else
     {
     cells[d] = data[d-insertions];
     d++;
     }    
}

alert(cells);
```